# How C++ debugger knows how to map lines between source and executable?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, debugging

If you put a breakpoint next to a line in VisualStudio, build the project with a custom tool, and run a configured VS debugger, how do the debugger know which "line" in the executable belongs to the breakpointed line in the source code? As the compiler is likely to optimise the code before crafting the executable.

Comment: The compiler generates debug information that maps CPU instructions to lines of code and vice versa. However this does not go well with optimizations. With those enabled debugging and skipping through lines of code often behaves weird as the generated program is not really in a one-to-one correspondence with the source code anymore.

Comment: For example, there's the [DWARF](https://dwarfstd.org/) debug information.

Comment: With a lot of extra data/meta information. For visual studio all that information is in the pdb files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As the compiler is likely to optimize the code before crafting the executable.

No, this is a big difference between a Debug build and a Release build.

A debug build will contain lots of extra information about your program than what is necessary to execute your program. In particular all names, classes, functions, and variables are in the debug build. The Debug build is mapping the built program with pretty much a 1 to 1 correspondence to your written code.

You will find that debugging an optimized program is very different from debugging a debug build.

When you find a bug that only manifests itself in optimized release builds you have a bit of a conundrum and need to put on another pot of coffee.